# Recommend RSS Parser PHP 4.3.9

Tags: php, rss-reader

I need to parse an RSS feed using PHP but the server only has PHP 4.3.9 at the moment. It is in the process of being upgraded, but central IT is taking their sweet time. Anyone have a favorite?

Comment: Wowwww. 22-Sep-2004 http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-4.php#4.3.9

Comment: Don't get me started. I've been begging to get PHP5 for over a year.

Comment: So crazy. I thought it was bad that I was pushing for 5.3 at work, but we're on 5.1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A google a day keeps the opprobrious comments at bay.

Here's a [list](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/php-rss-parsers/) of Php RSS parsers.

Comment: You are probably right, just wanted some recommendations from trusted stackoverflow users